# Django channel_layer can not get groups outside consumer

Tags: django, channel

In `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer` I can get `self.channel_layer.groups`:

```
print(self.channel_layer.groups)
{'asgi__group__PUBLIC': {'asgispecific.bfba9fdb3232407bba13e25e775b2492'}}
```

Outside consumer, in scipts:

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

// The code working
await channel_layer.group_send('PUBLIC', {'type': 'mark.price', 'data': {'price': 1}})

// But this not
print(channel_layer.groups)
{}
```

What can I do to get groups outside consumer? TKS!

```
channels                          3.0.4
channels-redis                    3.4.0
```